# How to select data where sum is greater than x

Tags: sqlite, sum, where-clause

I am very new to SQL and am using SQLite 3 to run basket analysis on sales data.

The relevant columns are the product ID, a unique transaction ID (which identifies the basket) and the product quantity.  Where a customer has bought more than one product type, the unqiue transaction ID is repeated.

I am wanting to select only baskets where the customer has bought more than 1 item.

Is there any way on SQLite to select the unique transaction ID and the sum of the quantity, but only for unique transaction IDs where the quantity is more than one?

So far I have tried:

```
select uniqID, sum(qty) from salesdata where sum(qty) > 1 group by uniqID;
```

But SQLite gives me the error 'misuse of aggregate: sum()'

Sorry if this is a simple question but I am struggling to find any relevant information by googling!

Comment: Please post your table structure (`.schema`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
select uniqID, sum(qty) from salesdata group by uniqID having sum(qty) > 1
```

"`where`" cannot be used on aggregate functions - you can only use `where` on `uniqId`, in this case.

Comment: on a similar note, if I wanted to count distinct uniqIDs where the quantity was more than 1, how would I do that?  I have tried select count(distinct uniqID) from salesdata having sum(qty) >1, as well as select count(distinct uniqID) from salesdata group by uniqID having sum(qty) > 1 and neither of these have worked

Comment: The question you asking isn't quite valid. If you are asking for distinct `uniqID`s, which `qty` do you use when there multiple rows with the same `uniqID`?

Comment: I'm guessing there should be a unique key on `uniqID` (not sure of the details in sqlite), so that you can't have any duplication.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to put any condition on the result you get with group by you must use having.

```
select uniqID, sum(qty) as sumqty from salesdata group by uniqID having sumqty > 1
```

you can put any of the condition with having normaly as in where.

```
having sumqty = 1 ,having sumqty < 1 ,having sumqty IN (1,2,3) etc..
```