# MSSQL select where sum greater than 0

Tags: sql-server

I need to return the results where the `amount_left` is greater than `0`. I tried this, but this gives wrong results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [item no_], 
            (SELECT Sum(quantity) 
             FROM   dbo.[auto kada sia$item ledger entry] 
             WHERE  [item no_] = a.[item no_]) AS 'amount_left' 
FROM   dbo.[auto kada sia$item ledger entry] AS a 
ORDER  BY a.[item no_]
```

How can achieve required result?

Comment: Show some sample data and the desired results

Comment: Thank you but i think there is no need for that because Sean gave me exactly what i needed

Comment: If so, I suggest you mark his answer as accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select data where sum is greater than x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111109/how-to-select-data-where-sum-is-greater-than-x)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT [item no_], SUM(quantity) AS 'amount_left' 
FROM   dbo.[auto kada sia$item ledger entry]
GROUP BY [item no_] 
HAVING SUM(quantity) > 0
ORDER  BY [item no_];
```